# Find files in Visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When I use "Find in files" in visual studio 2010 I don't know how to exclude some folders from search? The only option I have found is: add folders.

If I would like to search all folders and files in parent folder execept one (child) folder, there is no way to exclude this particular folder from search?

I can set the folder as hidden but than it wont be visible in VS - I don't wont that.
All I wont is to exclude it from search.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below given steps:

Step 1: Press look in button.
[image]

Step 2: Select the folders in which you want to search.
[image]

I hope this will helpful for u.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this doesn't help me. 
I would like to exclude one folder, not include.

Example:

I have folder A, which has many sub-folders(B,C,D,E,F,...) and many files in root of folder A(file1, file2, file3,...)

Now, I would like to search in all files in folder A and also in all sub-folders in folder A, except in sub-folder E.

So, how can I exclude folder E from search in folder A?

Comment: I look into Find dialog box in VS2010. But I don't think VS2010 gives any flexibility to exclude subfolder in find dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that the GUI is lagging because of too many search results. Try in setting, Find in Files -> Result options -> Display file names only = true